# What percentage of altcoins are based on Bitcoin?

Tags: altcoin

What percentage of altcoins share the same codebase as Bitcoin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Map of Coins](http://mapofcoins.com) is a great resource for this.

As of May 2016 they are tracking a total of 710 cryptocurrencies. Of those, 667 are based on Bitcoin's code, which is 94%!